# Vite proxy not redirecting to a different port

Tags: reactjs, proxy, vite

I want to connect my frontend (running on port 3000) with the backend (on port 5000).
I am trying to proxy requests sent to 'http://localhost:3000/api' be redirected to 'http://localhost:5000/api'.

Here is my vite.config file

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port : 3000,
    proxy: {
        '/api': {
          target: 'http://localhost:5000/',
          changeOrigin: true,
          secure: false,
          ws: true,
          rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/app/, '')
        }
    }
  }
})
```

I am using React so I also tried setting proxy to the package.json file of the frontend side.
Here is the package.json (react)

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.9",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^4.0.0"
  }
```

Here is the request code,
`const res = await fetch("/api"); console.log(res);`

Output in Console is as follows,

> Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost:3000/api', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}

I found that most of the answers to this question suggest to set 'secure: false' in vite.config file. But that didn't work for me.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I had the same in a vue app using vite